# flutter/ how to save geopoint using shared preferences

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I want to know how to save user's geopoint using shared preferences in my flutter app. It has 2 values(lat, long), but the following code was all I could write, which didn't work.

```
     static String sharedPreferenceUserGeopointKey = "USERGEOPOINTKEY";

     static Future<bool> saveUserGeopointSharedPreference(var geopoint) async {
     SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
     return await preferences.setDouble(
     sharedPreferenceUserGeopointKey, geopoint);
     }
```

later I retrieve this data like this;

```
static Future<dynamic> getUserGeopointSharedPreference() async {
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  double mylat = 
preferences.getDouble(sharedPreferenceUserGeopointLatKey);
  double mylong = 
preferences.getDouble(sharedPreferenceUserGeopointLongKey);
  return true;
}

bool result = await getUserGeopointSharedPreferences();
GeoPoint geopoint = result;
```

I can't put `result` into GeoPoint typed geopoint object, I can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call twice setDouble with different key.

Or try to use setStringList() method of shared preferences class.
In this case, you need to change from double latitude, logitude to list string.

```
     static String sharedPreferenceUserGeopointLatitudeKey = "USERGEOPOINT_LATITUDE_KEY";
     static String sharedPreferenceUserGeopointLogitudeKey = "USERGEOPOINT_LONGITUDE_KEY";

     static Future<bool> saveUserGeopointSharedPreference(var lat, var long) async {
        SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        await preferences.setDouble(
           sharedPreferenceUserGeopointLatitudeKey, lat);
        await preferences.setDouble(
           sharedPreferenceUserGeopointLogitudeKey, long);
        return true
     }
```

```
static Future<GeoPoint> getUserGeopointSharedPreference() async {
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  double mylat = 
preferences.getDouble(sharedPreferenceUserGeopointLatKey);
  double mylong = 
preferences.getDouble(sharedPreferenceUserGeopointLongKey);
  return GeoPoint.fromLatLng(name: 'Position', point: LatLng(mylat, mylong);
}

GeoPoint geopoint = await getUserGeopointSharedPreferences();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this, but I can't retrieve the geopoint I saved. When I put the saved geopoint into geopoint typed object, there's an error message `type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'GeoPoint'`. What is wrong?

Comment: It seems that you receive 'saveUserGeopointSharedPreference' method's response to GeoPoint variable. Because the 'saveUserGeopointSharedPreference' method's response type is 'bool' , try to do like this 'bool result = await saveUserGeopointSharedPreference(....)',

Comment: After trying that, how can I save `bool result` into GeoPoint typed object? I tried `GeoPoint geopoint = result;`, then only got the same error

Comment: The 'saveUserGeopointSharedPreference' method is just for save geopoint value to sharedpreference. When you call 'saveUserGeopointSharedPreference' method, you already have a geopoint variable because you pass the gepoint variable as a parameter. So you don't need to save result to Geopoint variable.

Comment: When you call 'loadUser....' method to get from sharedpreference geopoint value, you need to save result to geopoint variable at that time. In this example there is no 'loadUser...' method.

Comment: I edited my question with 'loadUser...' part. Please look and show me how to get the saved geopoint(2 doubles) and put them into GeoPoint typed variable.

Comment: I changed answer after modifying 'getUserGeopointSharedPreference' method. It seems that GeoPoint variable needs point's name. So you 'd better save point's name to sharedpreference also.

Comment: Thanks. You helped me solve this problem!